# PHP Singleton Database Query

Tags: php, database, singleton

In PHP, I have following Singleton Database Class:

```
class Database
{
    private static $instance;

    private function __construct()
    {
        self::$instance = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'Matthias', 'financecontrol', '3307');
        if (!self::$instance) {
            throw new Exception('Could not connect to database in function __construct.');
        }
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (!self::$instance) {
            self::$instance = new Database();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

}
```

Whenever I try to perform a query on the database in another PHP file, for example to check whether a user already exists:

```
function userExists($username)
    {
        try {
            $connection = Database::getInstance();

            $result = $connection->query("select * from user where username='$username'");
            if (!$result) {
                throw new Exception("Connection to database failed in function userExists.");
            }
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            $errorPager = new ErrorpageGenerator();
            $errorPager->generateErrorPage($ex->getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I get an error message "PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method Database::query() in User.php on line 44"

I've tried adding a query function in the Database class, but that did not seem to fix the problem. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add this method of course. But you cannot assign Database() and the mySQLi object to m_pInstance

so do:

```
class Database
{
  private static $conn;

  // ...
  public function __construct() 
  {
     self::$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'database', '3307');
     //...
```

and then

```
public function query($sql)
{
  return self::$conn->query($sql);
  // or 
  return mysqli_query(self::$conn, $sql);
}
```

**EDIT**

Working code:

```
class Database
{
  private static $instance = null;

  private static $conn;

  private function __construct()
  {
    self::$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'database', '3307');
  }

  public static function getInstance()
  {
    if (self::$instance == null) {
      self::$instance = new Database();
    }

    return self::$instance;
  }

  public function query($sql)
  {
    return self::$conn->query($sql);
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried something like that. But that produces this error: "Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting. " And the web page simply crashes.

Comment: Hm maybe with `self::$conn->query($sql)`? (I had it static first)

Comment: I edited and this code works for me, maybe it was because of `if (!self::$m_pInstance) {`. I 'nulled' it at the beginning and checked only if null

Comment: Ok, that seems about right.. But how do I execute queries on it now? This doesn't seem to work: $connection = Database::getInstance();

            $result = $connection->query("select * from user where username='$username'");

Comment: Now you could do `$result->fetch_array()` or choose something of your desire here: [MSQLi_Result](http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.mysqli-result.php), because as you see in the manual for mysqli_query: "Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a MySQLi_Result object."

Comment: Aah, my bad. It was a typo in one of my queries, that's why it still wouldn't execute. Works like a charm now! Thx ;)

Answer (score 1):

You get this error, because `Database::$m_pInstance` is contains an instance of `Database` class and **not** instance of MySQLi. You have created a "conflict" between to parts of the code:

```
public static function getInstance()
{
    if (!self::$m_pInstance) {
        self::$m_pInstance = new Database(); // << PROBLEM
    }

    return self::$m_pInstance;
}
```

Which overrides what your constructor does:

```
private function __construct()
{
    self::$m_pInstance = new mysqli( /* .. */ ); // PROBLEM
    if (!self::$m_pInstance) {
        throw new Exception('Could not .. blah');
    }
    else {
        return self::$m_pInstance;
    }
}
```

Even though the constructor assigns `self::$m_pInstance` the instance of MySQLi object, it gets overridden by `self::$instance = new Database();` right after.

Also, in php `__constuct()` method should not `return`, ever.

That said, i think is should warn you that **singleton is** considered to be **an anti-patterns**, and should be avoided. Your code also has the unintended side-effect, forcing you to have only one database (not connection, the database) available per application.

You might benefit from watching few lectures:

- [Advanced OO Patterns](https://vimeo.com/21173483) <sup>([slides](http://qafoo.com/talks/11_02_phpuk_advanced_oo_patterns.pdf))</sup>
- [Global State and Singletons](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI)
- [Don't Look For Things!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0)

Comment: +1 I have to agree, look for "Dependency Injection", it's a so much better approach!

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not look right.

first, you assign $m_pInstance a new Database instance. But then, in the constructor, you assign it a new mysqli instance. I am unsure how php handles this case, but it seems that it treats it as Database object as indicated by your error message. The Database class however does not have a query method.

So the solution would be to save the mysqli object in a different field and add getters and setters for it or delegate the methods to it.